# WordPress Calling Function Outside

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, themes, contacts

How to get value using 
    `<?php get_theme_mods('emailaddress') ?>` in file insde theme folder?

Actually I have registered a field to set email from WordPress customize section. `<?php get_theme_mods('emailaddress') ?>` is working fine when I display on WordPress pages or posts but it does not work when I try to get value on `formhandler.php` file inside theme folder.

When form is submitted, the form calls the file `formhandler.php` inside theme folder. So, I want to get value using `<?php get_theme_mods('emailaddress') ?>` to use email sent to email.

Why is `<?php get_theme_mods('emailaddress') ?>` not working inside `formhandler.php` file? This file just process the form and sends email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include wp-load.php at the top of formhandler.php. You will find wp-load.php in the root. If formhandler.php is on the root of your active theme then use the following include statement.

`<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>`